# Use Custom Field in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom field in Contract table. And now I want to use that field in the Report ar641000.rpx. But, when I go to Contract table, I don't see the custom field.

Comment: I think you just need to refresh the schema somewhere in the report writer for the custom field to show.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work. I don't know why I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see table changes (Acumatica versions or customization) you need to refresh the schema in your report. The report loads the table schema so it just needs refreshed.